# Analytic way to solve this geometrical problem

Tags: geometry, plane-geometry

In the ABC triangle, the P point divides the BC side with respect to BP:PC = 4:9, and the M point divides AP with respect to AM: MP = 5:8. What is the relation between the straight line BM and the AC segment?

I tried to draw it in scale but it is not strict. I need help with analytic approach.

Comment: You can use [Menelaus' theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Menelaus%27s_theorem) or its proof if you don't want to quote the theorem.

Comment: @OscarRascal - wouldn't that require a sixth point?

Comment: @Henry When there is something that you don't manage to see, don't frame your question as if it is a problem of what you are reading. Let me help you: "When I try it I need a sixth point", "I don't understand how to apply the theorem.".

Comment: @OscarRascal I am not convinced there is any relationship with the five points specified, but you seem to think there is an approach which works. So I queried your comment.  My thought (which may be wrong) is that if you fix $B$ and $C$, then by moving $A$, I would have thought you can make $BM$ very small and $AC$ close to $\frac{31}{26}$ times $BC$, or you can make $AC$ very small and $BM$ close to $\frac{124}{169}$ times $BC$; so by moving $A$ you can get any ratio between $BM$ and $AC$.

Comment: @Henry Then again it is not a problem in what you are reading. **You** do not see it.

Comment: @OscarRascal So please explain in more detail so I can see it better

Comment: Note that the problem asks for the relation between a $\bf line \rm$ and a segment.

Comment: @Mouvre What do you mean by the "relation between BM and AC"? Are you interested in the ratio $AN:NC$ where $C$ is the point of intersection of the lines $BM,AC$?